# Why does the Slider value change from an Integer to a Real, causing the Manipulate expression to break?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, slider

After I evaluate the following dynamic expression I encounter an unexpected behavior:

```
DynamicModule[{c, t, main, f},

  Manipulate[

   ControlActive[{x, y}, main[x, y]],

   {{x, c/2, "n1"}, 1, y - c, 1},
   {{y, n - c/2, "n2"}, x + c, n, 1},

   SynchronousUpdating -> False,

   Initialization :> (

     n = 300;

     c = 100;

     main[x_, y_] := main[x, y] = f[x, y];

   )

  ]

]
```

When this expression is evaluated from a *new kernel*, the output *without having touched any of the sliders* is as follows:

[image]

Notice how the value of `y` (labeled `"n2"`) is *as expected* and integer (`250`).

After *using* the second slider (which manipulates dynamic variable `y`) I get something like:

[image]

Notice how now the value of `y` is *not* an **integer**.

Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong and/or suggest a workaround?

ps. this is related to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170873/how-to-prevent-redundant-evaluations-over-a-sample-of-observations-in-a-dynamic) of mine.

Comment: This seems strongly related: [(43889)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43889/why-does-one-of-my-manipulate-integer-variables-get-turned-into-a-real)

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a bug as Mathe172 mentioned but they didn't fix. The only work-around I came up with was to take Integer of y with IntegerPart[y] as he mentioned below.

Comment: I think it should be considered a bug, but I also wish to point out that the dependence on the global symbol `n` is itself bug-prone.  E.g. try `n = 10; ...<OP's code>`.

Comment: @Michael E2 it broke the code when it was local to the module; 'n' is the length of the "Times" of a `TimeSeries` in the actual application of the code (please, see linked question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like a bug.  Here's fix, via explicitly constructing the slider ([`Manipulator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulator.html)):

```
n =.;
DynamicModule[{c, t, main, f},
 Manipulate[
  ControlActive[{x, y}, main[x, y]],
  {{x, c/2, "n1"}, 1, y - c, 1},
  {{y, n - c/2, "n2"}, x + c, n, 1, Manipulator[#1, {x + c, n, 1}] &},
  SynchronousUpdating -> False,
  Initialization :> (
    n = 300;
    c = 100;
    main[x_, y_] := main[x, y] = f[x, y];)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This isolates, or at least localizes the problem to having a `Dynamic` lower limit to the slider; the argument `x + c` automatically has `Dynamic[]` applied to it by `Manipulate` to make the slider limits dynamically dependent on `x` and `c`:

```
n =.;
DynamicModule[{c, t, main, f},
 Manipulate[
  ControlActive[{x, y}, main[x, y]],
  {{x, c/2, "n1"}, 1, y - c, 1},
  {{y, n - c/2, "n2"}, x + c, n, 1, Manipulator[#1, {Dynamic[x + c], n, 1}] &},
  SynchronousUpdating -> False,
  Initialization :> (
    n = 300;
    c = 100;
    main[x_, y_] := main[x, y] = f[x, y];)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Further isolation:

```
n = 300;

DynamicModule[{y = 200, c = 100, x = 50},   (* fails with Dynamic 1st argument *)
 {Manipulator[Dynamic[y], {Dynamic[x + c], n, 1}], Dynamic@y}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DynamicModule[{y = 200, c = 100, x = 50},   (* works with no Dynamic argument *)
 {Manipulator[Dynamic[y], {x + c, n, 1}], Dynamic@y}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DynamicModule[{y = 200, c = 100, x = 50},   (* works with Dynamic 2nd argument *)
 {Manipulator[Dynamic[y], {x + c, Dynamic@n, 1}], Dynamic@y}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
main[x_, y_] := main[x, y] = f[IntegerPart[x], IntegerPart[y]];)]]
```

But it still gives real value while slider is in motion but as soon as you lift mouse button it becomes integer.

Answer (score -1):

```
DynamicModule[{c, t, main, f},
   Manipulate[
       ControlActive[{x, y}, main[x, y]],
        {{x, c/2, "n1"}, 1, y - c, 1},
        {{y, n - c/2, "n2"}, x + c, n, 1},
        SynchronousUpdating -> False,
        Initialization :> (
          n = 300;
          c = 100;
          main[x_, y_] := main[x, y] = f[x, y];)
   ]
]
```

Comment: Please, read the code formatting guidelines in the help centre and re-format your code.

Comment: Hey @Oleg Blumenthal, thanks for the answer. I am reading your code and I fail to discern significant differences to what *@Michael E2* already proposed. Please, point me to the right direction, what am I missing?

Comment: @yosimitsukodanuri Actually, it is identical to your original code. -- Oleg, maybe the wrong code was posted?